# How can I get the heaviest element in a document using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get which element has maximun weight in the document or takes more timeto load? In this instance it is the image..

```
<html>

<body>

<p>This is light text</p>
<p>This is the heavy text </p>
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400" alt="100" width="100" height='100' />
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because DOM elements don't have "weight". I suspect you're talking about *size*, as in bytesize, but still no, because this isn't how HTTP works. The *entire* HTML document is downloaded as one file, so no `<p>` element is any "bigger" than any other `<p>` element; they're downloaded at the same time as part of the same HTTP request and neither takes "more time to load".

If you want to see the *actual* separate resources making up your page, your browser probably has a way of profiling this for you. Chrome's developer tools have a Network tab which is very useful.